# SQL in MS Access: When the order matters (like in the probability of a lottery problem)

Tags: sql, ms-access

EDIT 2:
I seemed to have solved this problem by adding prime numbers as a column, then multiplying the primes together gives me unique numbers with any combination. Then I will use another query to clean up the data set with "SELECT DISTINCT"

Thank you for your input.
////

So I barely even know how to ask this question which is why I came here.

I have a table that looks like this:
T1.F1, T1.F2, T1.F3

In .F2 there is a list of items with associated values in F3.

So lets say .F2 has the values of A,B,C with .F3 having the values 4,5,6

The user can choose two to five items in .F2 and I want to evaluate what the sum of .F3 will be.

In my case, I am trying to write a query where I get unique combinations of .F2 but the order doesnt matter. ie if the query finds A,B then I dont want it to return B,A.

I got to the solution where the order does matter: example I have a combination for A,B | 9 and B,A | 9.

Is what I am looking for even possible in MS Access?

Thank you for your input.

Edit: Here is a sample of the data as someone requested. You can see that its normalized. The issue is that in another form, the user can choose 2-5 of these options and I am ultimately trying to make a query with all the combinations and the resultant values. If they choose Expulsion  & Exchange, that is a valid option and the sum is 0. If they choose Expulsion and Harvest the sum is 20.

| F1 | F2 | F3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Void | Expulsion | 10 |
| Void | Starvation | 0 |
| Void | Provision | 0 |
| Void | Exchange | -10 |
| Void | Harvest | 10 |
| Void | Obscurity | 0 |
| Void | Remnants | 0 |
| Void | Dilation | 0 |
| Void | Instability | 0 |
| Void | Reprisal | 0 |

Sample of the result I am getting - which is correct, but the order doesnt matter so I am getting more rows than I need = Provision & Starvation is equivalent to Starvation & Provision- which makes things I want to do with this data more complicated - especially if they can choose 4 or 5 values. I left out the sum of values for simplicity.

| F1 | F2 | F3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Void | Expulsion | Starvation |
| Void | Provision | Starvation |
| Void | Exchange | Starvation |
| Void | Harvest | Starvation |
| Void | Obscurity | Starvation |
| Void | Remnants | Starvation |
| Void | Dilation | Starvation |
| Void | Instability | Starvation |
| Void | Reprisal | Starvation |
| Void | Starvation | Provision |
| Void | Expulsion | Provision |
| Void | Exchange | Provision |
| Void | Harvest | Provision |
| Void | Obscurity | Provision |

Comment: It's unclear what you have and what you try to achieve. Please edit your question and provude us a data sample formatted as a table, and an expected result

Comment: First rule of relational database design: never store multiple values in a single field, instead use child tables and relations to represent multiple items being related to one row. If you do that, it should be really easy.

Comment: thanks @ErikA. I edited the question to show the data. I do think that I followed good DB design and perhaps my original question was not clear. Let me know if you think the data structure needs to change and if so how. thank you.

Comment: thank you @AndreyBaulin I have edited. Please let me know if you have any suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: Ah, a lot more clear now but I still have no clue how that form and query where the user selects data work, and what your desired output is, exactly. Some guidance is here: [mre] and [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055/7296893)

Comment: thanks @ErikA. I think I am going to try add a column with prime numbers. then if I multiply them, I should be able to use "distinct" to get rid of the duplicates.

Comment: That sounds like a rather complicated approach, generation of prime numbers is computationally hard and I'd be surprised if this can't be solved using an incrementing sequence and by enforcing order and uniqueness on that sequence. But hey, if it works for you... Keep overflows in mind, when multiplying primes they become a more realistic risk than in most scenarios.

Comment: @ErikA thank you. I only have 40 or so records in the table so I am just hardcoding the primes in. Your idea of enforcing order sounds good - but its a bit beyond my skill level at the moment. Thanks again for your input!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to get for every selected value a list of remaining values. You can do it by self joining the table.
Data sample:

```
create table dual (
    dummy TEXT(50)
);

insert into dual(dummy)
values('X');

create table tbl (
    F1 TEXT(50), 
    F2 TEXT(50), 
    F3 INTEGER
);

insert into tbl (F1, F2, F3)
select * 
from (
select 'Void' as F1, 'Expulsion' as F2, 10 as F3 FROM Dual
union all
select 'Void', 'Starvation',    0 FROM Dual
union all
select 'Void', 'Provision', 0 FROM Dual
union all
select 'Void', 'Exchange',  -10 FROM Dual
union all
select 'Void', 'Harvest',       10 FROM Dual
union all
select 'Void', 'Obscurity', 0 FROM Dual
union all
select 'Void', 'Remnants',  0 FROM Dual
union all
select 'Void', 'Dilation',  0 FROM Dual
union all
select 'Void', 'Instability',   0 FROM Dual
union all
select 'Void', 'Reprisal',  0 FROM Dual
) as t
;
```

And a query:

```
select t1.F1, t1.F2, t2.F2
from tbl as t1
    inner join tbl as t2
        on t1.F2 <> t2.F2
where t2.F2 in ('Provision', 'Starvation')  and "<-- put your selected values there"
;
```